# CSS Transition easing in, but not out?

Tags: html, css

I added transitions on the images for the image gallery on this website https://sandbox.graphicandwebdesign.ca/karim-jamous/newsletter/index.html eases in (fades in), but instantly goes back to its original state, when the mouse goes off the image? Any way to have the transition reverse when you take your mouse off?

Comment: Include the `transition` on the non-hovered state.

Comment: Could you add your current solution please? The nested block of html and relevant css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the transition to the non-hovered state:

```css
.gallery img {
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1px);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

The rationale here is that when you're not hovering over the image the `:hover` rules no longer apply. So if the `transition` is declared under `:hover` it effectively ceases to exist the moment you exit the hover.

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```css
.gallery img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    
}

/*you need to use transition in image  here*/ 
.gallery img {
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1px);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery"> <img src="https://sandbox.graphicandwebdesign.ca/karim-jamous/newsletter/pic4.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="fourthpicture"> </div>
```